# For loop not completing iteration over array?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, python-3.5

I'm trying to learn how to code in Python and I decided to make an image scraper for Reddit as my first learning project. I've managed to get everything all set except my for loop to go over an array of subreddits isn't completing.

The list of subreddits is formatted in an array like so:

```
sub_list = ['pics', 'mapporn', 'wallpapers']
```

And then this is the double for loop I have that is supposed to go through each subreddit and download all images (by checking for urls ending in .jpg or .png).

```
for sub in sub_list:
    posts = u.get_subreddit(sub).get_hot(limit=post_limit)
    for image in posts:
        file_name = image.url
        extension = image.url[-4:]
        print (extension)
        if extension == '.jpg' or extension == '.png':
            try:
                wget.download(file_name, path)
            except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
                if err.code == 404:
                    pass
                else:
                    wget.download(file_name, path)
```

My issue is after the first dozen or so images the script stops and spits out this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the stack trace if that helps:

```
File "redditscrape.py", line 52, in <module>
 main()
File "redditscrape.py", line 27, in main
 create_folder()
File "redditscrape.py", line 31, in create_folder
 download_images()
File "redditscrape.py", line 44, in download_images
 wget.download(file_name, path)
File "C:\ProgLangs\Python35\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 527, in download
 filename = detect_filename(url, out, headers)
File "C:\ProgLangs\Python35\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 486, in  detect_filename
 names["headers"] = filename_from_headers(headers) or ''
File "C:\ProgLangs\Python35\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 258, in filename_from_headers
 name = fnames[0].split('=')[1].strip(' \t"')
```

I tried adding print statements at various points to find what is breaking it, but I assume for some reason the script is iterating over only the first item in the array and then stopping, but I have no idea why

Comment: There's no = in fnames[0].

Comment: just a guess: if image_url is an empty string then image_url[-4] will throw IndexError

Comment: I would condemn the `wget` module for its cryptic, unhelpful error messages, but it seems likely that `image_url` is emptystring

Comment: I added an if statement to check if image.url is not none, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `if image.url is not None` is not the same as `if image.url == ''`.

Comment: There is not enough information to tell what the problem is. However, it appears that `fnames` is empty or that there is no equal sign character in `fnames[0]`. Before you blame the wget library, verify that your arguments to `wget.download` are as expected (i.e. use pdb or `print` to check the values of the `file_path` and especially `path` since you haven't provided how that is being assigned.

Comment: @Apero, that is not what the stack trace says is wrong.

Comment: @TylerCrompton the path is just a folder name run through the os.mkdir() function

Comment: Have you ascertained that it's a valid path?